# C++ Class w/ struct 'undeclared identifier"

Tags: c++

So I am getting an error that my privates are not being declared when in use. I feel like my initialization in my cpp file might be the problem but there is nothing that I can see is wrong.

The errors I am getting are:

```
main.cpp:55:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MailingAddress'
    testStudent.setMailingAddress(MailingAddress);
main.cpp:56:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PhysicalAddress'
    testStudent.setPhysicalAddress(PhysicalAddress);
```

This is my Student.h file.

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Address
{
  string street, city, state, zip;
};
class Student{ 
  private:
    string name;
    Address MailingAddress;
    Address PhysicalAddress;
    double age;
  public:

    Student();
    Student(string name, Address MailingAddress,Address PhysicalAddress, double age);
    ~Student();

    void setName(string iname);
    void setMailingAddress(Address iMailingAddress);
    void setPhysicalAddress(Address iPhysicalAddress);
    void setAge(double iage);

    string getName();
    Address getMailingAddress();
    Address getPhysicalAddress();
    double getAge();
};

#endif
```

This is my .cpp file.

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <string>
//INITIALIZATION

Student::Student(string n,Address mA,Address pA,double a)
{
  name = n;
  MailingAddress = mA;
  PhysicalAddress = pA;
  age = a;
}
Student::~Student()
{
cout << "Instance removed from memory" << endl;
}

//SETTERS
void Student::setName(string name)
  {name = name;}

void Student::setMailingAddress(Address MailingAddress)
  {MailingAddress = MailingAddress;}

void Student::setPhysicalAddress(Address PhysicalAddress)
  {PhysicalAddress = PhysicalAddress;}

void Student::setAge(double age)
  {age = age;}
//GETTERS
string Student::getName()
  {return name;}

Address Student::getMailingAddress()
  {return MailingAddress;}

Address Student::getPhysicalAddress()
  {return PhysicalAddress;}

double Student::getAge()
  {return age;}
```

And my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    double age;
    string name;
    string street0, city0, state0, zip0, street1, city1, state1, zip1;


    cout << "Enter the student's name: ";
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Enter the student's age: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Enter the student's mailing address (street, city, state, zip): ";
    cin >> street0 >> city0 >> state0 >> zip0;

    cout << "Enter the student's physical address (street, city, state, zip): ";
    cin >> street1 >> city1 >> state1 >> zip1;

     // Add the proper lines of codes to create an instance of type Student. Name this instance testStudent
    Student testStudent;
    testStudent.setName(name);
    testStudent.setMailingAddress(MailingAddress);
    testStudent.setPhysicalAddress(PhysicalAddress);
    testStudent.setAge(age);
    // Note the next few lines of code will not compile until testStudent is declared and initialized

    // Printing using accessors
    cout << "Student Info:" << endl;
    cout << "\tName: " << testStudent.getName() << endl;
    cout << "\tAge: " << testStudent.getAge() << endl;
    cout << "Mailing Address: " << endl << "\t" << testStudent.getMailingAddress().state << endl
                    << "\t" << testStudent.getMailingAddress().city << endl
                    << "\t" << testStudent.getMailingAddress().state << endl
                    << "\t" << testStudent.getMailingAddress().zip << endl;

    cout << "Physical Address:" << endl << "\t" << testStudent.getPhysicalAddress().state << endl
                    << "\t" << testStudent.getPhysicalAddress().city << endl
                    << "\t" << testStudent.getPhysicalAddress().state << endl
                    << "\t" << testStudent.getPhysicalAddress().zip << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: please include the error message in the question. In what line is the error?

Comment: main.cpp:55:35: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'MailingAddress'
    testStudent.setMailingAddress(MailingAddress);
                                  ^
main.cpp:56:36: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'PhysicalAddress'
    testStudent.setPhysicalAddress(PhysicalAddress);

Comment: I will add the main.cpp since that's where the error is showcased

Comment: Just implement all the methods that compiler is telling you. Also `PhysicalAddress` is not declared in main.

Comment: It always helps to edit your problem to make it as short and simple as possible while still producing the error. It’s a good habit for debugging also. If your code is too long, a lot of people, like me, won’t bother reading it. Don’t edit this one though, you’ve already asked it.

Comment: True that Elliott, I thought the same thing when posting this however this is one of those cases where I am not even sure what to focus on since the error/solution seems hazy in my eyes.

Comment: @SeaBebop A reasonable **first step** for making a [mre]: go to the line that triggers the error message and delete everything after it. Well, not quite everything -- keep the closing braces so your braces are balanced. **Second step:** try removing all the lines *before* the problematic one, up to the function's opening brace. You probably will need to keep some variable declarations, but get rid of as much as you can. Your goal is to preserve the compiler error; if your code's logic falls by the wayside, so be it.

Comment: @JaMit Thanks for the guide, I will try to apply this next time.

Comment: I've copied your error messages from your comment into your question, but you should be including them in your question when you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
testStudent.setMailingAddress(MailingAddress);
testStudent.setPhysicalAddress(PhysicalAddress);
```

does not make sense. `MailingAddress` and `PhysicalAddress` are your private members in `testStudent` of type `Address`.

You have to create an `Address` first, from the data you got from the user, and then pass it to the `set*` methods.

Comment: I feel like this is probably the answer but i'm not understanding how to input it. Create an Address first? In my h file I created a struct name Address if that's what you mean.     ```struct Address
{
  string street, city, state, zip;
};``` Then from there I created the sets ```void setMailingAddress(Address iMailingAddress);
    void setPhysicalAddress(Address iPhysicalAddress);```

Comment: I mean an object of type `Address`. What you have at the moment is the definition of the type, `Address`, but you have not created any object in `main()`. You have to define one (`Address a;`), populate the members (`a.street = ...;`, etc.) and then pass it to the method (`setMailingAddress(a)`). And then the same for the physical one.

Comment: Yes! You're a genus it worked. Also had to add to my code "this->" to my setters for example ```void Student::setPhysicalAddress(Address PhysicalAddress)
  {this->PhysicalAddress = PhysicalAddress;}```. I'm not exactly sure why but adding "this->" in my setters aided in printing out my exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @SeaBebop You're welcome! I'm no genius, you will learn how to do it too! `this->` helped because you have used the same name for the parameter and the member, so putting `this->` disambiguates. In general, avoid using the same names (shadowing). A common way to do so is to add a prefix/suffix to all members, for example `_` for `MailingAddress_`.

Answer (score 0):

Error message is quite clear here. In scope of main MailingAddress and PhysicalAddress are not available.

Couple of points about code sample

1. Getters in Student class should be marked const
2. In setters, Address should be taken as const &. Same for Student constructor taking MailingAddress and PhysicalAddress as parameters.